# How to get the user details from the facebook login?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook PHP SDK. I need the user to login to my site using their facebook account and I need to store their email, first name and last name in my database. I am using this code to login the user

```
 $loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
        array(
            'scope'         => 'user_photos,user_videos,email,offline_access,publish_stream,user_birthday,user_location,user_work_history,user_about_me,user_hometown',
            'redirect_uri'  => $fbconfig['baseurl']
        )
);
```

My problem is how can I retrieve the information after the user login and rediret back to my site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something along the lines of..

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();
```

OR

```
$user = $facebook->api('/me');
```

This will return an array that includes all the public information that FB generally gives out. (i.e.- name, birthday, email, etc.)

Now I'm sure you can access the user's email as such,

```
$userEmail = $user['email'];
```

To check out everything it returns specifically,

```
print_r($user);
```

For more example code, check out [Facebook's PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php)

Answer (score 1):

here, this will give you array with available user data:

```
    $fbme =  $facebook->api('/me');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

> https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=[facebook
>   returned access token]

This will give you the user detail. For [Reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)